# Reactor SubscriberContext not working for ServerRequest Body

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-webflux, project-reactor

When we try to set the context from the server Request body, we are not able to extract the serverRequest Body.
When we set a POJO we are able to retrieve the object from the context

```java
  public Mono<ServerResponse> processuser(ServerRequest serverRequest) {
  
    return serverRequest
        .bodyToMono(FederationUserRequest.class)
        .flatMap(
            federationUserRequest ->
                Mono.subscriberContext()
                    .flatMap(ctx -> ctx.get("fed"))
                    //when we set the context from serverRequest it doesn't reach the next flatpMap
                    //when we set the context from Mono.just(new FederationUserRequest()) it works.
                    .flatMap(fur -> ServerResponse.ok().bodyValue(Mono.just("data")))
        .subscriberContext(ctx -> ctx.put("fed", getRequestBody(serverRequest)));
  }

  private Mono<FederationUserRequest> getRequestBody(ServerRequest serverRequest) {
 
    Mono<FederationUserRequest> req = Mono.just(serverRequest.bodyToMono(FederationUserRequest.class);
    return Mono.just(new FederationUserRequest()); -> Works, adds to context as MonoLiftFusable
    return req; -> Does not Work, adds to context as MonoLift
  }
```

Comment: do you mind also including the code that doesn't work?

Comment: also, could you include any error logging or stacktraces if any occurs during the error?

Comment: @MichaelMcFadyen This line of code doesn't get executed 

```java 

   .flatMap(fur -> ServerResponse.ok().bodyValue(Mono.just("data")))
```

The confounding thing is there are no errors in the logs, it returns abruptly with a 200 with no body.

The use case here may not mean anything but, I wanted to keep the example simple.

Comment: thanks for responding. On initial review, I would say that the fact you are consuming the body twice using `bodyToMono` is unusual. This would normally cause an error to be raised. I can't explain exactly why it is failing silently but my guess is that the `ctx.get("fed")` is emitting a COMPLETE signal causing the `flatMap` to be skipped.

Comment: @MichaelMcFadyen That seems like a very plausible response. What we were trying to solve for is extracting the Request and setting it into the context to be accessed further down the chain.

All the examples and code snippets online are for static values...

Would you recommend how can we capture the value from the serverRequest and set it into the context.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The issue was quite simple. It was staring at me all this while.
When we invoked

```
return serverRequest
        .bodyToMono(FederationUserRequest.class)
```

The subscribe() gets invoked implicitly..

Us trying to call

```
    Mono<FederationUserRequest> req = Mono.just(serverRequest.bodyToMono(FederationUserRequest.class);
```

again basically was completed subscriber.

The code should've been

```java
 public Mono<ServerResponse> processuser(ServerRequest serverRequest) {
  Context context = Context.of("fed", Mono.just(serverRequest.bodyToMono(FederationUserRequest.class));


    return Mono.subscriberContext(ctx -> ctx.get("fed"))
        .flatMap(
            federationUserRequest ->
                Mono.subscriberContext()
                    .flatMap(ctx -> ctx.get("fed"))
                    .flatMap(fur -> ServerResponse.ok().bodyValue(Mono.just("data")))
        .subscriberContext(context);
  }
```